# Ajax response - remove the scripts and styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to make an AJAX call where I retrieve another page, completely. Then I would trim the html received to what I would like to see (styling wise) by removing or adding different stuff. As below:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/booking-standard-mykad.html",
    dataType: "html",
    ifModified: true,
    asnyc: true,
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function(data) {

        data = $(data);
        data.find(".somecssclass").remove(); 
        //lots of other modifications

        $('.book-now').html(data); //then I would display it here

    }
});
```

Now the problem is, I don't seem to be able to remove the styles and scripts that are as well fetched in the head. I would like to keep some of the content in the head, what's below the head, in the body and in the footer.

What I have tried and failed:

```
data.find("title").nextUntil("script[src='http://thedomain.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/js/porto.js']").andSelf().remove();

//removing whatever there is from <title> to a certain <script> fetched
```

As well, I have tried the `load()` function in jQuery, but since I have lots of JS functions in the footer and body that I would need, it didn't quite work. Hence I used Ajax.

Any thoughts on how to remove certain `<scripts>` , `<meta>` and `<link>` tags being fetched?

Comment: is there a typo ? `data.find(".somecssclass").remove` doesn't make the function call, it should be `data.find(".somecssclass").remove()` with curly brackets

Comment: I think there are issues when enclosing HTML strings with `script` tags in jQuery. At least, that is what I am finding while testing to find a solution

Comment: I have as well tried `data.find("script").remove();` but then this removes ALL of my `<script>` tags, including the ones in the body that I need.

Comment: How about removing ALL script tags, EXCEPT the one you need: `data.find('script').not('script[src="scriptThatINeed.js"]').remoev()`

Comment: Also, be sure to `@` the person you are responding to so that we get a notification of a reply

Comment: @CarlK, thanks loads for the idea. But that would also remove many of the inline `<script>` tags that I need. As well, sorry for not using `@` earlier!

Comment: @Sina, you should post the HTML `<head>`, so we could figure out the correct selector.

Comment: We could do this to not remove all inlines but it is starting to get messy: `data.find('script').not('script[src="scriptThatINeed.js"]').not(':not([src])').remove()`

Comment: @CarlK, that gave me _SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL_

Comment: @Neverever, it's a rather very long `<head>`, hence I'd wanna remove most of it. but I can tell you that it starts with `<title>` and ends with `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thedomain.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/js/porto.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by fetching data to a third page using jQuery `load()`, removing whatever styles that I want, and then using an iframe to pull the data from that third page to my destination. All good and fast.